# ng-click Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, geocoding, angularjs-ng-click

I'm reverse geocoding when a user clicks on a point on a google map like so:

```
geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                console.log(results[1]);
```

At this stage the console log for results[1] looks like

```
Object {address_components: Array[4], formatted_address: "Rathmines, Co. Dublin, Ireland", geometry: Object, place_id: "ChIJN6MDC6kOZ0gRIhArCabX9o4", types: Array[2]}
```

But then I try and pass that object in to an ng-click function when the user taps on the infowindow with the address that I have popping up, like so:

```
ng-click='addressPicked("+results[1]+")'
```

I get the error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] 
at column 23 of the expression [addressPicked([object Object])] starting at [Object])].
```

I have this working in another application, but I am just passing through a lat & long string.

Do I need to convert the object to something else before trying to pass it through as a parameter?

Anyone come across this error before with ng-click?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: if `results` variable in scope then do try `ng-click='addressPicked(results[1])'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without looking at the full code, my guess is that you are getting the error because

```
ng-click='addressPicked("+results[1]+")'
```

is converting `results[1]` to its string representation `[object Object]` and hence the error.

Try using without inner quotes

```
ng-click='addressPicked(results[1])'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
ng-click='addressPicked('+results[1]+')'
```

Because result is a variable (object) must be passed without quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

For people trying to pass an **object** through to the next function neither of the above answers work, exactly. In that case you need to use:

`ng-click='addressPicked(' + JSON.stringify(object) + ')'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="class1" id="id1" data-ng-click="click1(arg)" data-ng-class="{class2: expression, class3: expression, class4: expression }">
```

I was getting the similar error when my expression was like above and when I have changed the expression like below the issue got resolved. Adding the single quotes ('') across all the classes for ng-class.

```
<div class="class1" id="id1" data-ng-click="click1(arg)" data-ng-class="{ 'class2': expression, 'class3': expression, 'class4': expression }">
```